# Android SDK. Can't start AVD

Tags: android, android-emulator, windows-10, cpu-architecture, android-x86

***Problem:***
  I'm using only command line tools.  AVD just worked fine some time ago.  Now with various configurations I get only "Starting emulator for AVD..." which simply closes without any error messages and leaving emulator.exe in Task Manager for eternity.

***What I've tried:***

- Various devices, API's, RAM above and below 768, with/without Host
  GPU etc;
- Reinstall Java;
- Reinstall Android SDK;
- Run emulator from command line just launches emulator.exe without any errors;
- Delete .android folder in User's folder;
- Set ANDROID_SDK_HOME variable;
- Run SDK Manager.exe/AVD Manager.exe with/without elevated Admin rights;

  **verbose key gives me the following log**:

`emulator:Found AVD name 'jkll'
emulator:Found AVD target architecture: arm
emulator:Auto-config: -engine classic (arm default)
emulator:Looking for emulator-arm to emulate 'arm' CPU
emulator:Probing program: C:\Soft\Android\android-sdk\tools/emulator-arm.exe
emulator:return result: C:\Soft\Android\android-sdk\tools/emulator-arm.exe
emulator:Found target-specific 32-bit emulator binary: C:\Soft\Android\android-sdk\tools/emulator-arm.exe
emulator:Adding library search path: 'C:\Soft\Android\android-sdk\tools/lib'
emulator:  Found directory: C:\Soft\Android\android-sdk/add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-17\images\armeabi-v7a\
emulator:  Found directory: C:\Soft\Android\android-sdk/add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-17\images\armeabi-v7a\`

**Configuration I am working on:**

- Windows 10 x64
- Android SDK Manager 25.1.1
- Java JDK 8 Update 91
- i5 CPU with 24GB of RAM

Any suggestions? TY.

Answer (score 2):

I tried all the mentioned solutions. But strangely, I reduced my windows 10 laptop's resolution (from 3840 x 2160 to 1360 x 768) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

With your verbose I found you are using arm architecture devices.As you are using i5 processor,Windows10 x64  I would Suggest you to use x86 or x86-64 architecture for your devices for this you have to Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM) from SDkManager.

Hope this helps let me know.

Comment: Still the same.

I just noticed there are more than one emulator executables in \tools directory: emulator.exe, emulator-arm, emulator-x86 etc. Launching AVD with images of different architecture from GUI everytime triggers only emulator.exe. Trying to use emulator-x86 I get an error about missing Qt5Core.dll, Qt5Widgets.dll and Qt5Gui.dll. Is this normal behavior?

Comment: you should try this :Just open your terminal execute your_qt_installpath/version/compiler/bin/windeployqt.exe YourApplication.exe. It will automatically copy all the required libs and stuff into the folder, where your exe is located and you can just distribute it.

Comment: have you enabled virtualization in BIOS? If not first enabled it in BIOS here is link that help may help you with http://superuser.com/questions/991323/virtualization-bios-setting-windows-10 and after that try running intelhaxm-android.exe in administrative mode let me know if these help....

Comment: Nothing to worry about emulator executables....they are there ...by default executables files that come with the setup..

Answer (score 0):

After changed the CPU of my computer and updated sdk, I encounter this problem too.

Now I temporarily solve the problem `emulator-x86 I get an error about missing Qt5Core.dll, Qt5Widgets.dll and Qt5Gui.dl`:

copy `*.dll` files in `sdk\tools\lib\qt\lib` to `sdk\tools` where the emulator-x86.exe in.